# log analysis tool to define search pattern cross log entries

Tags: logging, analysis

Currently i'm using vmware log insight to do log analysis.
Is there any log analysis tool can define a search pattern cross log entries?
e.g.
my log looks like these:

```
2018-03-20T15:44:14.785Z node-92008 Hostd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for vpxuser started
2018-03-20T15:44:14.785Z node-92008 Hostd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for vpxuser` ends with status success
```

So the action started log is in one line and the action ends is in one line.

Is there any tool i can define an search pattern e.g. find each pair of "started" and "ends" to counter how many times i did in logs?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep to get the records

`grep -E 'vpxuser (started|ends with)' file.log`

I'm assuming the backtick in '*vpxuser` ends with*' is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Unomaly is a good tool for log analysis. Its pretty simple, you just have to ingest your logs into Unomaly, it will tokenize and profile your log data and group the logs with similar profiles. Give it about week to learn the patterns of behaviour and then it will start identifying what is repetitive and reduce it, only surfacing anything that is unique. You can also make correlations between systems.